# how to list all databases in progress-4gl 9.1 D?

Tags: progress-4gl

i'm trying to get all databases like in the DataDictionary, but in a programmatic way! Is that possible?

Answer (score 6):

```
DEFINE VARIABLE iDatabase AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

REPEAT iDatabase = 1 TO NUM-DBS:
    DISPLAY LDBNAME(iDatabase) .
END.
```

LDBNAME returns the logical name of a database. You can also use PDBNAME to get the physical name.

Information about tables, indexes, etc. can be retrieved from the Virtual System Tables (VST) tables (prefixed with underscore). Examples can be found in Progress Knowledge Base (e.g. entry P8005).